# Unable to find class in mapper.xml using mybatis plus and spring boot

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, mybatis-mapper

Unable to find class while parsing mapper.xml in mybatis plus.
Having json response class with below structure.

```
@Data
@Builder
@Setter
@Getter
public class StudentCourseDetailsRes {

     @Valid
     @JsonProperty("courseDtls")
     private ArrayList<CourseDtls> courseDtlsList;
     
     @Setter
     @Getter
     @Builder
     public static class CourseDtls {
       
        private String courseName;
        private String courseDuration;

        @Valid
        private ArrayList<ErrDetails> errorDetailList;

        @Setter
        @Getter
        @Builder
        @Data
        public static class ErrDetails {
           private string errorCode;
           private string errorMessage;
        }

     }
}
```

Defined mapper.xml like below

```
<mapper namespace="mapper.StudentMapper">
    <select id="studentproc" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="java.util.Map" resultMap="stuCourse">
     {call package.student_course_proc(
#{stuId, jdbcType=VARCHAR,javaType=java.lang.String,mode=IN},#{courseName, jdbcType=VARCHAR,javaType=java.lang.String,mode=OUT},#{couseDetails, jdbcType=VARCHAR,javaType=java.lang.String,mode=OUT},#{errorCode, jdbcType=VARCHAR,javaType=java.lang.String,mode=OUT},#{errorMessage, jdbcType=VARCHAR,javaType=java.lang.String,mode=OUT}
   </select>
  <resultMap id="stuCourse" type="entity.StudentCourseDetailsRes">
     <collection property="courseDtlsList" ofType="entity.StudentCourseDetailsRes.CourseDtls">
        <collection property="courseDtls">
          <result property="courseName" />
          <result property="courseDuration"/>
          <collection property="errorDetailList" ofType="entity.StudentCourseDetailsRes.CourseDtls.ErrDetails">
          <collection property="courseDtls">
            <result property="errorCode"/>
            <result property="errorMessage"/>
          </collection> 
         </collection>
        </collection>
     </collection>
  </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

While running application facing issue like ClassNotFoundException: can't find class class entity.StudentCourseDetailsRes.CourseDtls

Please guide is it right way to configure mapper.xml in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Able to Resolve the issue by adding procedure out parameters to paramMap.